# Updating Dictionary Keys and Values From Second Dictionary

Tags: python, loops, dictionary

Assistance in updating working_data dict from raw_data dict.  If the key already exists in working_data, update value.  If not, create new key and value.

```
working_data = {newkey1 : '', newkey2 : '' , newkey3: '', newkey4: ''} 

raw_data = {raw1: 'var1', raw2: 'var2', raw3: 'var3', raw4: 'var4}
```

Comment: how do you make the association between `raw_data` and `working_data`? Is it the trailing numbers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to replace or add to the `working_data`:

```
for k, v in {k.replace('raw','newkey'): v for k,v in raw_data.items()}.items():
    working_data[k] = v
```

If you only want to update numbers (e.g. if there is a `raw5` in `raw_data` but not a `newkey5` in `working_data` and you don't want to add `newkey5` to `working_data`:

```
for k, v in {k.replace('raw','newkey'): v for k,v in raw_data.items()}.items():
    if k in working_data:
        working_data[k] = v
```

Comment: Thanks!  So this works.  Can you help me in adding an if statement?  The `raw_data` can sometimes be up to 30 items, but I only want to show a static 15 items in the `working_data`.   How would write to only pull the keys you want and dump the rest?  Does that make sense?

Answer (score 0):

The keys look like they're variable names. That immediately presents you with a problem for how you are going to insert these values. You can't use a variable name as a key. Indexing the dictionary with something like `working[new1]` will make `working` look like `{new1's value : 'var1'}`. So if `new1 = 'mystring'`, you'll have `{'mystring' : 'var1'}`. I assume you want to preserve the names of these variables, so you'll have to come up with a way to serialize variable names, likely by hardcoding another dictionary with a key-value mapping that maps each `newX` with a string representation of it.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you would include only values you want.

```
result = {k: v for k, v in working_data.items() if v!= ''}
```

Comment: @Mark M. Was this response helpful? If so, could you upvote it? I'm new here and it would help me a lot. Thanks!